# What do parentheses in a Perl regex do?

Tags: regex, perl

I have been trying several regular expressions in the substitution operator:

```
$str =~ s/^0+(.)/$1/;
```

converts 0000 to 0 and 0001 to 1

```
$str =~ s/^0+./$1/;
```

converts 0000 to empty string, 000100 to 00, 0001100 to 100.

what difference is the parentheses making?

Comment: On a side-note, that replacement might be more clearly written `s/^0+(?=.)//` using a lookahead assertion instead of a capture.

Comment: You might try going through _Learning Perl_ to pick up the basics. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bit of a misuse to me - you need the () to identify what's your match.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

> Capture buffers
>
> The bracketing construct ( ... )
>   creates capture buffers. To refer to
>   the current contents of a buffer later
>   on, within the same pattern, use \1
>   for the first, \2 for the second, and
>   so on. Outside the match use "$"
>   instead of "\". (The \ notation
>   works in certain circumstances outside
>   the match. See the warning below about
>   \1 vs $1 for details.) Referring back
>   to another part of the match is called
>   a backreference.

So basically you can use

```
if ($str =~ /^0+(.)/) { print "matched $1"; }
```

If you have more than one grouped matches they will be $1, $2, $3... etc e.g.

`if ($str =~ /(0*)(1*)/) { print "I've got $1 and $2"; }`

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to get value in the $1 or
>   $2 you need to group the pattern in
>   the regular expression. Without
>   grouping if you want to get the value,
>   it will display error message, if you
>   use the following statement.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

> In the second statement, if you use
>   the $1 variable without grouping. So
>   that time the value of $1 will be
>   empty. So it will replace the matched
>   value into empty.

Answer (score 0):

> In case of first expression , the $1
>   has matched pattern .
>
> In case of second expression , there
>   will not be $1 variable , because it
>   does not has any
>
> grouping.